# Custom shipping rate logic

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, price-rules, rules

I have created a custom shipping method. I need to implement the following logic:

> **Shipping rate = Item weight * Item quantity * Zone rate**

How to get zone rates in collectRates method?

Comment: what you mean by zone rate?

Comment: region wise tax rate